# I have more errors within mysql

Tags: php, syntax-error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and email) VALUES ('','','')' at line 1

i am now getting this error for specifically this line:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_member (username, password and email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
```

Comment: Couldn't you ask about it in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919519/i-have-a-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected

Comment: i think this parameters are empty check them $username,$password,$email

Comment: @Haim Evgi: But empty values should not lead to a syntax error.

Comment: you right, its another issue because in the error was written : VALUES ('','','')

Comment: Empty values should throw an error if those columns are not allowed to be null, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_member (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
```

Comment: @Mason no, it cannot be the same. READ IT

Comment: he must also have different fieldnames in db!!
and shouldn't he be escape-quoting the values ? sql wants string values to be quoted ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't use the 'AND' keyword like that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_member (username, password, email) VALUES ('$user','$pass','$mail')";
```

Secondly, the error message indicates that at the time the query is run the 3 variables, $user, $pass and £mail are empty.

Answer (score 0):

What are the names of your columns? if it's really "password and email", you should use backticks surronding them:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_member (`username`, `password and email`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
```

otherwise use @Shivan-Raptor 's sollution?